# Docker can't exec init scripts while run Docker start command

Tags: apache, tomcat, docker, centos7

I created a Docker image based on CentOS 7. I expect the Docker container can automatically start Apache and Tomcat services while I execute the Docker run command.

My docker start command is:

`sudo docker run --privileged -ti --name apache-tomcat-mobile --rm -v /software:/software -p 81:80 local/web-apache /app/scripts/start-web.sh`

But I always got this error：

> exec format errorFATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 7332a91875c1aefb0d6c5160a69fe1c21058c06673b6e4058c81a8641af53baa: exec format error

My start-web.sh just has two task, one is the tomcat startup.sh, antoher is the httpd -k start.

I have been set the enough privilege for the start-web.sh.

while I execute 
`sudo docker run --privileged -ti --name apache-tomcat-mobile --rm -v /software:/software -p 81:80 local/web-apache /bin/bash, there are no error happen.

```
The docker file I used based on CentOS7. The bas docker file is :
FROM centos:7
MAINTAINER "edao99" <jianghy_bj@hotmail.com>
ENV container docker
RUN yum -y swap -- remove fakesystemd -- install systemd systemd-libs
RUN yum -y update; yum clean all;\
(cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done);\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]

The actually docker filed used for apache and tomcat is inherited from the base docker. The apache docker file is:
FROM local/c7-systemd
RUN yum -y install gcc; yum clean all;
RUN yum -y install httpd; yum clean all;
RUN yum -y install apr-util-devel; yum clean all;
RUN yum -y install httpd-devel; yum clean all;
RUN yum -y install wget; yum clean all;
RUN yum -y install make; yum clean all;
RUN yum -y install tar; yum clean all;
RUN systemctl enable httpd.service
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

I searched the solution from internet and I didn't find a similar issue.
Can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: We need to know a little more. Can you provide your Dockerfile and especially any ENTRYPOINT instructions? Also provide the actual contents for start-web.sh.

Comment: Hi, I added the docker file I used in question descriptions because the comment don't allow write too many characters.

Comment: That's the right place to put it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the script you run into the container before you can use it as a command. You'll need to add a line to the Dockerfile such as:

```
COPY start-web.sh /app/scripts/start-web.sh
```

Make sure you place `start-web.sh` in the build context.

Also, your build file would be a lot simpler if you got rid of the systemd stuff. If you have to have more than one process, look into using a simpler process management tool such as Supervisor or Runit or just write your own shell script to start the services.